# Объединение двух столбцов в mysql

Tags: mysql, select

сделал запрос но хочется чтобы было красиво как на этом примере

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мой запрос:

```
SELECT a.id, a.datetime, c.Name, b.login, 
NULLIF(
    CASE WHEN c.ID = 1 OR c.ID = 2 THEN '0'
    ELSE a.amount END, '0') AS Prikhod,
NULLIF(
    CASE WHEN c.ID = 3 OR c.ID = 4 THEN '0'
    ELSE a.amount END, '0') AS Raskhod 
FROM balance AS a 
LEFT JOIN users AS b ON a.user_id=b.id
LEFT JOIN operatsion AS c ON a.type=c.ID 
WHERE owner_id ='3'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хочется чтобы столбцы 'Name' и 'login' были в одном столбце например: куплен пакет для пользователя "6666666", был в одном столбце как на примере можно ли это сделать запросом. куплен я переименую на "куплен пакет для пользователя"

Comment: А кто мешает? CONCAT() в руки - и объединяй любые значения и литералы.

Comment: Akina, спасибо большое, не думал что это так легко)

Comment: сделал CONCAT() все получилось а как сделать жирным имя пользователь в запросе как в примере это возможно?

Comment: Сервер в ответ на запрос возвращает plain text, и о существовании форматирования он даже не подозревает. Это забота клиента.